# Recyclerview not showing both values

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display messages inside Recyclerview that I'm retrieving from the server via Json. The issue that I'm having right now is; It doesn't show both messages (received & sent).

It does show only IF I comment out `um.setM_msg(jsonObject.getString("my_msg"));` and `holder.m_msg.setText(mData.get(position).getM_msg());` OR the other and it will show up but not both at the same time.

Is this some layout issue? would like to get some advice, Thanks in advance.

Retrieving data and setting up the adapter

```
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        messages um = new messages();
                        um.setS_msg(jsonObject.getString("s_msg"));
                        um.setM_msg(jsonObject.getString("my_msg"));
                        lstMessages.add(um);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }catch (JSONException e2){
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            rv_msg.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            chat myadapter = new chat(this, lstMessages);
            rv_msg.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

Adapter class

```
public class chat extends RecyclerView.Adapter<chat.MyViewHolder> {

    public Context mContext;
    public static List<messages> mData;
    RequestOptions option;

    private static final int SENDER_LAY = 0;
    private static final int MY_LAY = 1;

    public chat(Context mContext, List<messages> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view =null;
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if(viewType==SENDER_LAY)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_row_left_item,parent,false);
            viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        }
        else
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_row_right_item,parent,false);
            viewHolder= new MyViewHolder(view);
        }

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (mData.get(position).getS_msg() != null && mData.get(position).getS_msg().length() > 0){
            return SENDER_LAY;
        } if (mData.get(position).getM_msg() != null && mData.get(position).getM_msg().length() > 0){
            return MY_LAY;
        } else {
            return MY_LAY; //temp
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.s_msg.setText(mData.get(position).getS_msg());
        //holder.m_msg.setText(mData.get(position).getM_msg());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView s_msg, m_msg;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            m_msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.m_msg);
            s_msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.s_msg);

        }
    }
}
```

Both of the XMl looks like this (chat_row_left_item & chat_row_right_item)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/s_msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:background="@color/white"/>


    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use else if in you getItemViewType override function.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mData.get(position).getS_msg() != null && mData.get(position).getS_msg().length() > 0){
        return SENDER_LAY;
    }else if (mData.get(position).getM_msg() != null && mData.get(position).getM_msg().length() > 0){
        return MY_LAY;
    } else {
        return MY_LAY; //temp
    }
}
```